# Things to consider when adapting a Magento 1.7 module/extension to Magento 1.2?

Tags: magento, module, payment

So, I have developed a Magento module/extension on version 1.7.

There are a few clients that run previous versions, like 1.2.

I tried to install the older version and I have already got problems: It doesn't want to run as expected on PHP 5.3.

My questions are:

- What should I consider when adapting the module ? (say for version
  1.2)
- Where can I find some good documentation for this version in
  particular ? (I didn't find any on the official magentocommerce.com)
  ?

In order to be more specific, if it helps at some point, it is a payment module.

Answer (score 1):

Collections are not used so deeply in 1.2 as in the next verisons. For example, in grid you need to transform collection to array (asArray or to Array method of collection, as I remember) before preparing.